# How to update a class property from a different class?

Tags: excel, vba

I will start off by posting my code so far:

**dhOrder Class Module**

```
Option Explicit

'List of class properties
Public PONumber As String
Public ShipToName As String
Public Phone As String
Public Address1 As String
Public Address2 As String
Public ZIP As String
Public City As String
Public State As String
Public dsU As Long
Public dsF As Long
Public dsM As Long
Public dsD As Long
Public skuList As collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set skuList = New collection
End Sub
```

**dhSkuList Class Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private mSKU As String
Private mQty As Long
Private mDS As Long
Private mDSF As Long
Private mDSM As Long
Private mDSD As Long

Public Property Get SKU() As String
    SKU = mSKU
End Property

Public Property Get Qty() As Long
    Qty = mQty
End Property

Public Property Get dsU() As Long
    dsU = mDS
End Property

Public Property Get dsF() As Long
    dsF = mDSF
End Property

Public Property Get dsM() As Long
    dsM = mDSM
End Property

Public Property Get dsD() As Long
    dsD = mDSD
End Property

Public Property Let SKU(ByVal Value As String)
    mSKU = Value
    UpdateDSFee
End Property

Public Property Let Qty(ByVal Value As Long)
    mQty = Value
End Property

Public Property Let dsU(ByVal Value As Long)
    mDS = Value
End Property

Public Property Let dsF(ByVal Value As Long)
    mDSF = Value
End Property

Public Property Let dsM(ByVal Value As Long)
    mDSM = Value
End Property

Public Property Let dsD(ByVal Value As Long)
    mDSD = Value
End Property

Private Sub UpdateDSFee()
    ' Update DS fee count based on the SKU
    Select Case Right(SKU, 1)
        Case "F": mDSF = mDSF + 1
        Case "M", "R": mDSM = mDSM + 1
        Case "D": mDSD = mDSD + 1
        Case Else: mDS = mDS + 1
    End Select
End Sub
```

**OrderImporter Module**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DyehardDropShipOrderImporter()
    
    Dim poSheet     As Worksheet        'Original Dyehard PO worksheet
    Set poSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    'Dyehard PO layout validation
    Dim columnAHeader As String
    Dim columnBHeader As String
    Dim columnCHeader As String
    
    columnAHeader = poSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
    columnBHeader = poSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
    columnCHeader = poSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value
    
    If columnAHeader = "Purchase Order #" And columnBHeader = "Ship To Name" And columnCHeader = "Shipping Line 1" Then
        ' The file matches the expected column layout of a Dyehard PO file
        GoTo POValidated
    Else
        ' The file does not match the expected column layout of a Dyehard PO file
        MsgBox "Please ensure you are running the Dyehard Drop Ship Importer on a valid Dyehard PO file.", vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, "Incorrect PO Format Detected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
POValidated:
    'Create a new sheet named "Drop Ship Order Importer" in current workbook
    Dim dsSheet     As Worksheet        'Drop Ship Import worksheet
'    Set dsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
'        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
'    dsSheet.Name = "Drop Ship Order Importer"
    
    'Copy data from original PO to order collection
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    lastRow = poSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim orders          As collection        'Main order collection
    Dim cOrder          As dhOrder        'Order class object
    Dim cSkuList        As dhSkuList        'Order SKU List class object
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim r               As Long
    
    Set ws = poSheet
    Set orders = New collection
    
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        
        Set cSkuList = New dhSkuList
        
        'Retrieve Order Number for key assignment
        Dim PONumber    As String
        PONumber = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "A").Value2)
        
        'Check if key already exists
        Set cOrder = Nothing: On Error Resume Next
        Set cOrder = orders(PONumber): On Error GoTo 0
        
        'If key doesn't exist, create a new class object
        If cOrder Is Nothing Then
            Set cOrder = New dhOrder
            
            cOrder.PONumber = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "A").Value2)
            cOrder.ShipToName = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "B").Value2)
            cOrder.Address1 = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "C").Value2)
            cOrder.Address2 = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "D").Value2)
            cOrder.City = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "E").Value2)
            cOrder.State = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "F").Value2)
            cOrder.ZIP = CStr(Format(ws.Cells(r, "G").Value2, "00000"))
            cOrder.Phone = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "H").Value2)
            
            cSkuList.SKU = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "I").Value2)
            cSkuList.Qty = CLng(ws.Cells(r, "J").Value2)
            cOrder.skuList.Add cSkuList, cSkuList.SKU
            orders.Add cOrder, PONumber
        Else
            cSkuList.SKU = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "I").Value2)
            cSkuList.Qty = CLng(ws.Cells(r, "J").Value2)
            cOrder.skuList.Add cSkuList, cSkuList.SKU
        End If
        
    Next
    
'    'Copy orders from order collection to Drop Ship sheet
'    Dim i           As Long        'Order counter
'    Dim s           As Long        'SKU counter
'    Dim q           As Long        'Quantity counter
'
'    Dim SKU         As Variant
'
'    For i = 1 To orders.Count
'        'CHANGE CUSTOMER NUMBER TO 287342 BEFORE PRODUCTION!!!
'        'CHANGE CUSTOMER NUMBER TO 287342 BEFORE PRODUCTION!!!
'        'CHANGE CUSTOMER NUMBER TO 287342 BEFORE PRODUCTION!!!
'        'CHANGE CUSTOMER NUMBER TO 287342 BEFORE PRODUCTION!!!
'
'        dsSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = "407340"        'MOM Customer Number
'        dsSheet.Range("AA" & i).Value = "UPS"        'Ship Method
'        dsSheet.Range("BX" & i).Value = "EDII"        'Order Type
'        dsSheet.Range("AF" & i).Value = orders.item(i).PONumber        'PO Number
'        dsSheet.Range("DR" & i).Value = orders.item(i).PONumber        'PO Number
'        s = 33        'Column AG
'        q = 34        'Column AH
'        For Each SKU In orders.item(i).skuList
'            dsSheet.Cells(i, s).Value = SKU.SKU
'            s = s + 2
'            dsSheet.Cells(i, q).Value = SKU.Qty
'            q = q + 2
'        Next SKU
'        dsSheet.Range("AT" & i).Value = orders.item(i).Address1        'Address 1
'        dsSheet.Range("AU" & i).Value = orders.item(i).Address2        'Address 2
'        dsSheet.Range("AV" & i).Value = orders.item(i).City        'City
'        dsSheet.Range("AW" & i).Value = orders.item(i).State        'State
'        dsSheet.Range("AX" & i).Value = orders.item(i).ZIP        'ZIP Code
'        dsSheet.Columns("AX").NumberFormat = "00000"
'        dsSheet.Range("AQ" & i).Value = Split(orders.item(i).ShipToName)(1)        'Last Name
'        dsSheet.Range("AR" & i).Value = Split(orders.item(i).ShipToName)(0)        'First Name
'
''        Dim lastcolumn As Long
''        Dim rng     As Range
''        Set rng = Range("CQ" & i, "CU" & i)
''        lastcolumn = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
''            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
''        dsSheet.Cells(i, lastcolumn).Value = dsSheet.Cells(i, lastcolumn).Value & "  Order #" & orders.item(i).poOrderNumber & "  FEDEX THIRD PARTY #748958380" & "  TRACKING________________"
'
'    Next i
'
'    'AutoFit Drop Ship sheet
'    With dsSheet.Cells
'        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
'        .EntireRow.AutoFit
'    End With
    
End Sub
```

In the dhSkuList class module, I have a sub that updates a property in the class itself (UpdateDSFee). How can I adjust my code to update the property in the dhOrder class instead of dhSkuList? For example, if there is a SKU ending in F, I want the dsF property in dhOrder class to go up by 1.

Also, is my use of private variables correct/necessary?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an instance of `dhSkuList` to be able to operate on the containing instance of `dhOrder` then you can add an `Order` field to `dhSkuList` and set it to the order object.

```
cSkuList.SKU = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "I").Value2)
cSkuList.Qty = CLng(ws.Cells(r, "J").Value2)

Set cSkuList.Order = cOrder  '<<<

cOrder.skuList.Add cSkuList, cSkuList.SKU
```

For example in `dhSkuList`:

```
Private mOrder as Object

Public Property Set Order(ByVal value As Object)     
    Set mOrder = value 
End Property   

Public Property Get Order() As Object     
    Set Order = mOrder 
End Property
```

I'd say it's probably a better design to have the container Order class take care of its own updates though, by inspecting each `SkuList` as it's added.

Comment: I added the line you mentioned and the following to dhSkuList class and am getting an object variable or with block variable not set error:

`Public Property Let Order(ByVal value As Object)
    mOrder = value
End Property


Public Property Get Order() As Object
    Order = mOrder
End Property`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Object-type property declarations require `Set` not `Let`,  and you're missing `Set` from the bodies of both.

Comment: Crap, forgot about Let vs. Set. Does this create a potential recursion problem? I added a watch to the main collection (orders) and each SkuList expands with an Order property that expands that contains the same SkuList property and so on...

I do agree about your design suggestion and I will work towards implementing that. I'm newish to VBA, so still trying to figure out the best way to design stuff!

Comment: That referencing thing is only an issue in the Watch window, and it's not much different from how many objects in the Excel object hierarchy have their own reference back to (eg) `Application`